# Script link formatting for cross-browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, css, header, squarespace

I'm referencing the following scripts in the header of https://livingibogaine.squarespace.com. I'd post the HTML separately, but it's mountainous.

The scripts trigger great in Safari! Firefox and Chrome don't read them at all. **Am I formatting them incorrectly?** Or this likely a bug in the Squarespace platform?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.wlvrtn.com/sites/www.livingcleanibogaine.com/css/style-five.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wlvrtn.com/sites/www.livingcleanibogaine.com/js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
      $("#page-nav").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
    });
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 800);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` both `chrome` and `firefox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possibly because you are loading the page over `https`, but your scripts over `http`. Chrome can be a bit fussy about doing insecure things like that. Try changing the jQuery link to `src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"` and access your `jquery.sticky.js` file from an https site also.

EDIT: jquery.sticky.js is hosted on a https CDN here - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.sticky/1.0.0/jquery.sticky.min.js

Comment: What about the CSS? Even that isn't triggering for Firefox / Chrome, and there's no https conflict there.

Comment: Your CSS is also being served over http rather than https. This is also insecure. If you are serving a page over https, you should always serve all resources over https as well. When I open your site in Chrome, the developer tools give me the follow warning for the css.

`[blocked] The page at 'https://livingibogaine.squarespace.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.wlvrtn.com/sites/www.livingcleanibogaine.com/css/style-five.css': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function($){
      $("#page-nav").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
    });
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 800);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

See also @JoshLowry answer